# Galaxy S with Cyanogenmod 10 (stable): File Manager needs root permission to access the external SD card

Tags: cyanogenmod, samsung-galaxy-s, external-sd

I have an SGS with CM10 installed.
The file manager and Apollo, both of which come with CM10 by default, are having issues reading the SD card.

File Manager needs SU permissions to see it.

Apollo just crashes when I try to open a file from it.

Other File Manager apps have no issue. My PC sees both internal and external memory. Winamp and Play Music have indexed songs from the external SD card and can play them.

Any idea where the problem might be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the permission for the mount point of the external sd card got messed up.

This is how it looks like on a SGS with CM 9.1:

```
shell@android:/ $ ls -l /mnt/ 
d---rwxr-x system   sdcard_rw          1970-01-01 01:00 emmc
```

Comment: I fixed permissions from Clockworkmod a few times and the problem persisted. I'll check the permissions next year and come back. Thanks.

Comment: Or this year. This is what I see: `emmc -> /storage/sdcard1` `drwxr-xr-x` and `sdcard -> /storage/sdcard0` `lrwxrwxrwx`.